# SELINUX add process_type access to file_type

Tags: selinux

nslcd.service cannot start because SELINUX is enabled.  It doesn't allow nslcd to access `/etc/openldap/certs/*`.

The permissions on the files in that directory are:

```
-r--r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:slapd_cert_t:s0 1220 Apr 11 11:41 cert.crt
```

Is there a way for me to add `nslcd_t` access to files labeled `slapd_cert_t`?

As a workaround, I have used `semanage permissive -a nslcd_t` to make the process type `nslcd_t` permissive. SELinux does not deny access to permissive process types, but the AVC (SELinux denials) messages are still generated.

Comment: Why would the LDAP client daemon need to access the LDAP server's certificates, rather than the applicable CA certificate(s)? Are you using a self-signed certificate for your LDAP server?

Comment: We are not using a self-signed cert.  The certificates we are issued have been placed in /etc/openldap/certs and rehashed.  Our environment has multiple CAs.
Your question led me to do more digging.  It appears that I inherited an old config.  I copied the certs into /etc/ssl/certs/, changed /etc/nslcd.conf to point there, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Nice :-) Since you've resolved the issue, you should [write an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and later come back to [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). That way the question gets closed and this may be useful for someone else down the line.

Comment: I'd say your modified configuration seems to make way more sense than the inherited old one. Please follow the advice of Peregrino69 and write a self-answer, wait 48 hours, then accept it.